# When do symmetrical matrices commute?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, noncommutative-algebra

For context I was taking an optimization course and at one point we used the restriction by line to prove the concavity of $\log det(X)$. Let $g(t) = \log det(X + tV)$ with $V \in S_{n}$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

This leaves us with $X + tV \in S_{n}$ then decompose it as follows:
$$X + tV = X(I + tX^{-1}V) = X(I + tX^{-\frac{1}{2}}X^{-\frac{1}{2}}V) = X(I + tX^{-\frac{1}{2}}VX^{-\frac{1}{2}})$$

And here's the problem: I can't see the justification (which must be clear, since it's not spelled out) for being able to commute $X^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ with $V$. I know that if the product of symmetrical matrices is symmetrical then they commute, but here we don't know if the matrix $X^{-\frac{1}{2}}V$ is symmetrical.

I often see commutations that I do not understand and that are not justified, so maybe there are rules I don't know (especially when working with symmetric or positive definite matrices).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What properties are we assuming for $X$? Also is $S_n$ the group of permutations?

Comment: Sorry, $X \in S_{n}$ where $S_{n}$ is the set of symmetric matrices. It also says that $X$ can always be decomposed as $X^{\frac{1}{2}}X^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: For symmetric matrices, we can always find a square root. I do not see why we would be able to commute the square root through $V$ though. Sorry :(